# Embed angular.js app in resizable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, pagination

I'm using angular.js to paginate a list of data on my website (found the code at http://www.angularcode.com/angularjs-datagrid-paging-sorting-filter-using-php-and-mysql/). The user can decide, how many rows of data he wants to display on a single page. Because of that, the table is constantly resizing. Is there a possibility to embed the app into a dynamically resizing div in order to properly append a footer-div at the bottom of the website?

Here is the code of the app:

```
<div id="app-container" ng-app="myApp" ng-app lang="en">
    <div ng-controller="customersCrtl">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">PageSize:
                    <select ng-model="entryLimit" class="form-control">
                        <option>25</option>
                        <option>50</option>
                        <option>100</option>
                        <option>500</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-7">Filter:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()" placeholder="Filter" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div id="url-amount" class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
                    <h5>Filtered {{ filtered.length }} of {{ totalItems}} total URLs</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                    <th>URL&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('url');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
                    <th>Status Code&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('statuscode');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
                    <th>Category&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('statuscategory');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
                            <td>{{data.url}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.statuscode}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.statuscategory}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h4>No URLs found</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">    
                    <div pagination="" page="currentPage" max-size="10" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;"></div>            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

and the styles:

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

[image]

The footer div overlaps the angular.js app instead of beeing appended below.

Comment: From question not clear how it works now (what problem with footer do you have) and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @OlgaAkhmetova When I'm trying to append a <div> at the bottom of the page it doesn't show up on the bottom but overlaps the table generated by the angular.js app. Therefore I would like to embed the angular app into a div. The problem is the table is constantly resizing so I'm not able to give the div a static value. My question is if there is a possibility to embed the angular app into a div that resizes based on the size of the table created by the angular.js code.

Comment: sorry, but I still don't understand you. `div` IS resizable by default unless otherwise stated

Comment: @OlgaAkhmetova I've added some info in the question.

Comment: I think that problem is in style of your `app-container` element like `float:left` or something, because if I just copy your html code to codepen, all seems good. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGRLZm

Comment: @OlgaAkhmetova Thank you very much for your help! Bootstrap was causing some troubles together with my code. I was finally able to fix the error by embedding the ng-app div into another div with class="row".

Comment: Glad you solved the problem)